# Laravel belongs to relation with where condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Am using 2 tables say "video" , "video_tags".And my video table will store video records and the video_tags will store the tags Now I really need to front end I need to get the video collection with a particular tag only. For that, I put condition like below:

```
$resultQuery = Video::with('Videotags')
    ->where('event_date', $this->event_date)
    ->orderBy(DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(`videos`.`from_time`,'%h:%i%p')"));
```

and my video model looks like

```
public function Videotags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'video_tag', StringLiterals::VIDEOID, 'tag_id')
        ->whereNull('video_tag.deleted_at');
}
```

Now  I need to filter the video records with video tag is  5,
I put where condition in the model file

```
->where('tag_id', '5')
```

Also, I tried

```
$resultQuery = Video
    ::with('Videotags', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->where('tag_id', '<>', '5');
    })
    ->where('event_date', $this->event_date)
    ->orderBy(DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(`videos`.`from_time`,'%h:%i%p')"));
```

and it is not working, where condition won't work for belongsToMany ? or any other way?

Comment: You must [Query the Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: this I tried with where condition "=" and "<>", seems not worked

Comment: I mean something like `Video::whereHas('Videotags', function ($query) {
    $query->where('id', 5);
})...`

Comment: its working by using like below
      $resultQuery = Video::whereHas('tags', function ($query) { $query->where('video_tag.tag_id', 83); })
            ->where('event_date', $this->event_date)->orderBy(DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(`videos`.`from_time`,'%h:%i%p')"));

thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer

```
   $resultQuery = Video::whereHas('tags', function ($query) { 
      $query->where('video_tag.tag_id', 83); 
   })->where('event_date', $this->event_date)
   ->orderBy(DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(videos.from_time,'%h:%i%p')"));
```